# get() in picasso cannot be applied to (android.content.context)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have the following code on android studio, after I followed a tutorial video. However, in the tutorial video, the uploader used:

`implementation 'com.android.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

while I had to use

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Adapter Class

```
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.viewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ItemActivity> mExampleList;

    public adapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemActivity> exampleList)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {
            View v = 
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.itemlayout, parent, false);
        return new viewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) 
    {
        ItemActivity currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageUrl();
        String creatorName = currentItem.getCreator();
        int likeCount = currentItem.getLikeCount();

        holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(creatorName);
        holder.mTextViewLikes.setText("Likes: "+likeCount);

        Picasso.get(mContext).load(imageUrl). 
        fit().centerInside.into(holder.mImageView);//get() in picasso 
                                                     cannot be applied to 
                                                 (android.content.context)
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
        public TextView mTextViewLikes;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_likes);
        }
    }

}
```

As stated above, the Picasso line gives me the error: get() in picasso cannot be applied to (android.content.context)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Picasso `2.71828` you dont need to supply `Context` in `Picasso.get()`

For more information see the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 3):

Picasso `with(Context)` hast been renamed to `get()`

Check [this commit](https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae)

Answer (score 2):

`Picasso#get()` doesn't have a context. If you need to use a different context, you can use `new Picasso.Builder(mContext).build();`

Or, `Picasso.get()` will suffice.

Comment: can you provide proper Code please for picasso,as mContext is Not Working